# Android CoordinatorLayout show ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a CoordinatorLayout that is setup using the default Tabbed Activity in Android Studio. This activity has the scroll flags as follows:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

I have a 'scroll to top' assigned to an icon in the TabLayout via the pager adapter:

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter.feedFragment.scrollToTop();
```

When I click this, I would also like to force the ActionBar back into view. I had assumed that I would be able to call:

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

However, that isn't working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`appBarLayout.setExpanded`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html#setExpanded(boolean))